# Am I using flexbox right? Can't seem to get vertical alignment to work - other threads dont seem to have answer

Tags: html, css

I am building a website from an image given to me to practice (it comes from his employer as a test). I know he mainly used flexbox in the entire site, so im trying to stick with that (havent learned grid at all). On the top of the website is a sort of 'header' that includes some button links, a logo, and a search bar in the middle. The searchbar is located vertically about halfway down the entire header.

I am trying to do that without using a margin hack, but none of the typical align or justify commands seem to work. I also set a height, still nothing. Any thoughts?

Included a height property, also tried various commands like: align-item, align-items, align-self, justify-content, etc.

---

```
#searchbar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 15rem;
  flex: 1;
  /* margin-top: 15px; */
  margin-right: -5px;
  text-align: center;
```

}

I want to move the search bar down to the middle of its parent element, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply align-self: center to the #searchbar - asyou can see - the display: flex is applied to the parent, then  align-self to the div. This centeres it withing the parent. Then you will need to apply that same logic to the contents of the searchbar div itself - in order to center them within it. and adding justify-content: center to center the content horizontally within the parent div as well.

I have applied a yellow background on the parent div, a red border on the searchbar div to demonstrate the relationship and the centering of the inner div and a blue border on the text withon the searchbar div to show its centered..

```css
#wrapper {
  height : 200px;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow
}


#searchbar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 15rem;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

#searchbar-content {
border: solid 1px blue;

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="searchbar">
  <span id="searchbar-content">Search bar content goes here</span>
</div>
```